# Tagging words in a corpus

Tags: perl

I am a linguist by trade and use Perl to help me organize my data so I am not at all proficient and my solutions are not very streamlined :) My problem today, is that I want to tag all occurrences of the items in a wordlist in a corpus of example sentences.

I wrote a (sloppy) script for another experiment but it only identifies the first word from the list that it finds and then moves to the next. I need it to find all words in all sentences and on top of that, assign a tag in the second column of the wordlist. My head just cannot get around how to do this. Help!

So say my wordlist looks like this (a tab delimited .txt file with 1 column for the word and 1 for the tag to be assigned, each word and tag on one line):

```
boy (\t) ID01
sleep (\t) ID02
dog (\t) ID03
hungry (\t) ID04
home (\t) ID05
```

The original corpus would just be a tokenised .txt with one sentence per line, eg:

```
The boy and his dog met a hungry lion .
They needed to catch up on sleep after the dog and the boy came home .
```

I ideally want output like the following:

(1) A tagged corpus in the format:

```
The boy [ID01] and his dog [ID03] met a hungry [ID04] lion .

They needed to catch up on sleep [ID02] after the dog [ID03] and the boy [ID01] came home [ID05].
```

(2) A list of the words with their tags that were not found in the corpus at all. I previously just printed the words to a .txt and this worked fine.

I hope this makes sense!
Here is what I have used previously to find sentences containing the words. This code is based on a much simpler word list without the ID tags and I was just looking for any matches to see if my corpus at least contained some examples. How can I best adapt it? This took me ages to write but I am learning!

Thank you!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %words;
my %print;

open (IN2, "<LemmasFromTagset.MG.2022-10-17.txt"); #the wordlist

while (my $s = <IN2>)
{
    chomp $s;
    my $lcs = lc $s;
    $words{$lcs} = 1;
}
close(IN2);
open (OUT, ">TaggedSentences.txt"); #the final output with tagged sentences
open (OUT2, ">NotFound.txt"); #words for which there are no sentences

foreach my $word (sort keys (%words))
{
    open (IN,"<all-sentences_cleaned.tagged.desentensised.txt"); #the corpus
    
    print $word."\n";
    
    my $count = 0;
    
    while(my $s = <IN>)
    {
        chomp $s;
        my $lcs = lc $s;
        if ($lcs =~ /^(.*)(\W+)($word)(\W+)(.*)$/)
        {
        print OUT $word."\t".$s."\n";
        $count ++;
        }
    elsif ($lcs =~ /^($word)(\W+)(.*)$/)
    {
       print OUT $word."\t".$s."\n";
       $count ++;
    }
    }
    
    if ($count == 0)
    {
    print OUT2 $word."\n";
    }
    close(IN);
}
close(OUT);
close (OUT2);
```

Comment: It would help if you could give us a sample of the output you want.

Comment: Hi Dave, I did try to do that in my question, but the editor is not showing the markup I added to the two sentences (just brackets with the IDs from the wordlist). I am trying to get it back somehow

Comment: May I suggest lexical filehandles?  (`open my $fh, ...`)  Bareword filehandles like `FH` [aren't recommended](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Assigning-a-filehandle-to-a-bareword).  Additionally, lexical ones automatically close when you want them to, with few [caveats](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Automatic-filehandle-closure).

Comment: @MarissaGriesel You have to use code formatting to make tags show

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I quite follow the logic of your code, but the replacement is easy enough.

1. Process the key file, make the key lower case and the value the tag in your `%words` hash. E.g. `$words{$key} = $value`. We can do that quick and easy with a do statement, where we slurp the file and process it with a map statement.
2. Make a regex to search for the key words, using the alternator `|`.
3. Read the input file, find and capture the key word with parens `()`, keep the matched word with `\K`. Replace (add) a space, tag open, your hash value made lower case with the `\L` escape sequence, and tag close.
4. Print.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %words = do { 
    open my $fh, "<", "words.tsv" or die $!;
    map { chomp; split /\t/ } <$fh>;
};
my $find = join '|', map lc, keys %words;
while (<DATA>) {
    s/($find)\K/ <$words{ "\L$1" }>/ig;
    print;
}


__DATA__
The boy and his dog met a hungry lion .
They needed to catch up on sleep after the dog and the boy came home .
```

If you want to make this program flexible, you can just replace `<DATA>` with `<>` and use the file name to process as argument, and then redirect the output to a file e.g.:

```
$ perl words.pl corpus.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help and your layout of the solution. It helps me to learn to "think like a programmer".

Comment: your code works beautifully to solve my tagging problem. Thanks again. I just need to still figure out a few things: (1) to also process lemmas in the tagset that are multiword units and (2) to also print a list of the tags not found in the corpus so that I can add more examples of those tags to the dataset and (3) how to only match full words in the corpus. Currently the code will match "lioness" to the tag for "lion" and since I am working with a language with a rather productive morphology, I don't want that.

Comment: @MarissaGriesel My pleasure. You may wish to ask a new question, usually that is the best way to get fresh input. I'm not sure what you mean by "lemmas in the tagset". Also, I could have sworn that I replied to your first comment. Some strange moderator going round deleting comments again. This comment will probably be deleted too, since I mentioned moderators, so be sure to read it quickly. ;)

Comment: read and noted :D thanks! I am going to try solve my remaining challenges at least partially myself first before I ask another question - I have to force myself to learn somehow!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you might benefit from two hashes for your wordlist, one for the IDs and one for the frequencies.  For the IDs:

```
my %words2ids;  # will be { "sleep" => "ID02", "boy" => "ID01", ...}

open(my $lemmas, "...") or die;
while (my $line = <$lemmas>) {
  chomp($line);
  my ($word, $id) = split "\t", $line;
  $words2ids{ lc($word) } = $id;   # note: lc($word)
}
```

Next, go through the raw corpus' tokens, counting and tagging the ones you're interested in:

```
my %freq;
open (my $output, "...") or die;
....
while (my $line = <$corpus>) {
  chomp($line);
  my @tokens = split ' ', $line;
  foreach my $token (@tokens) {
    my $lct = lc $token;
    if (my $id = $words2ids{ $lct }) { # false if no entry
      $freq{$lct}++;     # add one to the frequency count
      $token .= " $id";  # cheat a bit and append $id to the aliased token
    }
   }
  # now reconstruct the input line for our output
  say { $output } "@tokens"; # use feature qw(say)
}
```

In the above we run through the corpus once, instead of once per word in your taglist.

Now your "NotFound" entries are those keys in `%words2ids` that do not appear in `%freq`:

```
open (my $notfound, "...") or die;
foreach my $word (sort keys(%words2ids)) {
  next if exists $freq{$word};  # skip if we've seen it
  say { $notfound } "$word $words2ids{$word}";
}
```

That's not terribly idiomatic nor particularly slick Perl — and it certainly isn't tested! — but I think it fairly captures your problem and the approach you want to take.

Comment: This is such a help. Thank you! I am going to go through the code and comments today to test and adjust if needed.

Comment: I have been spending a bit of time learning from your code and comments. How would I adjust the code if I didn't want to print the sentences without any tags? I tried moving the "say" command up into the if statement that matches the tokens so that it only prints to the output when the conditions are true (when the token is found in the corpus), but then it prints the sentence for each token that matches and I end up with an even bigger set of sentences. Must I add an elsif then?

Comment: @MarissaGriesel, at the top of the outer loop (`while (my $line = ...)`), you can always initialize a false/zero variable `my $lemmas_seen`, and increment this every time you note an interesting word (inside the `if` branch of the inner loop).  Then, at the bottom of the outer loop, you'd `say` the modified sentence only if `$lemmas_seen` was true or greater than zero.  Let me suggest that further improvements be taken up as separate questions here, thanks.